# bootstrap panel space between columns

Tags: html, css, panel, bootstrap-4, col

I have this page:

http://www.nuzoo.it/it/prodotti-robot/raro-robot-videosorveglianza-mobile

and I want to remove space between the panels in "Funzionalità" section.
Every panel has this code:

```
#bor_panel {
border-radius: 12px;
border: 2px solid #287396;
padding: 20px;
width: 170px;
height: 170px;
display: flex;
 }

#bor_panel span {
 margin: auto;
 display: none;
 }

 #bor_panel:hover img {
  display: none;
 }

 #bor_panel:hover span {
  display: inline;
 }
```

I have already tried "margin-left/right:0", "padding-left/right:0", "margin:0", "no-gutter" but nothing change...any idea?
Thanks

------EDIT-------

I would this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC7D1.jpg

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To improve this question; consider combining your `html` and `css` into **one code snippet** to *accurately demonstrate the issue described*, and for *user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting*.

Comment: how much space do u want between them, please hardcode and mention it, meanwhile u can remove the default margin in row by margin:0;

Comment: @satyampathak as I said, I have already tried "margin:0", "margin-left:0", etc

Answer (score 1):

Add a class "no-gutters" to the row
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Comment: You didn't mention that in your post. Did you add the class to the row, not the column? That was my mistake, just edited the answer

Comment: I have used the class "no-gutters" and I added in my column, but nothing change.

Comment: A yes I see, it looks like you have an older version of bootstrap, the "no-gutters" class is not available

Comment: Sorry but the "no-gutters" class, is simply a css code. I don't think that my version of Bootstrap is the problem...